# SQL SELECT Statement to reference table twice

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I've tried numerous SQL joins and searched stackoverflow, and to no avail.

Effectively, I've got a baseball database with two tables. A "teams" table (that has a team_id and team_name), and a "games" table (for when one team plays another, when, where etc).

I want to create an SQL query that given a teams.team_name value, the query returns the last 10 games played by the given team (at "home" in their stadium, or "away" at a competitor stadium), and the *name* (teams.team_name) of both teams in the given game, based on the corresponding teams.team_id in the games table.

Tables:

## TEAMS

> ROW #1 (team_id) 1, (team_name) "Yankees"
>   ROW #2 (team_id) 2, (team_name) "LA Dodgers"
>   ROW #2 (team_id) 3, (team_name) "Red Sox"
>   ...

## GAMES

> ROW #1 (game_id) 1, (home_team_id) 1, (away_team_id) 2, (date_played) ...
>   ROW #2 (game_id) 2, (home_team_id) 3, (away_team_id) 2, (date_played) ...
>   ROW #3 (game_id) 3, (home_team_id) 2, (away_team_id) 3, (date_played) ...

The SQL query I would want to return would be:

> "Home Team"-----"Away Team"----"Date Played"
>   Yankees-----------LA Dodgers------##/##/####
>   Red Sox-----------LA Dodgers------##/##/####
>   LA Dodgers ------Red Sox----------##/##/####

This query almost gets me output I require, but I want "team_name" from the "teams" table, but adding that to the SELECT creates problematic output

```
SELECT games.home_team_id,
   games.away_team_id
FROM games,
     teams
WHERE games.home_team_id = teams.team_id
  AND teams.team_name = "Yankees"
  OR games.away_team_id = teams.team_id
  AND teams.team_name = "Yankees"
ORDER BY games.date_played DESC LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when you want to use the same table multiple times in a single query, presumably in two different capacities, you give your table an *alias* - a name that you list right after the table name in the `FROM` or `JOIN` clause:

```
SELECT h.team_name, a.team_name, g.date_played
FROM Games g
JOIN Teams h ON h.team_id = g.home_team_id
JOIN Teams a ON a.team_id = g.away_team_id
WHERE ...
```

`g`, `h`, and `a` are aliases for their respective tables.

Note the use of `JOIN` syntax instead of listing all tables in the `FROM` clause and constraining them in the `WHERE` clause. This is a much cleaner syntax that should be used in queries with joins.